# Whats better to use in C++11 , Zero or NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Nowadays, with C++11, Whats recommended to use, `Zero` or `NULL`? The first of the second if?

```
int * p = getPointer();

if( 0 == p ){
    // something
}

if( NULL == p ){
    // something
}
```

**UPDATE:** I forget the new

```
if( nullptr == p ){
    // something
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** the examples are to show the options to write null pointer, I know is more pleasant to write `if( !p )`.

Comment: [Yoda Conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) look funny!

Comment: Remember the difference between null and 0... 0 is an integer, where as null means "nothing" - hence why you should use nullptr (and why 0ptr doesn't exist)

Comment: @VBAssassin: 0 as a literal is a particular beast, as it is both an integer and 'something' that converts to a null pointer. When used as a pointer, 0 **is** a null pointer. Note that NULL *is* defined in C++ to be a literal 0 (integer type) unlike in C where it is `(void*)0`. Of course the better option in C++11 is `nullptr`, but in C++03 I prefer `0` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The other answers are right.  But I wanted to say a little more about **why** `nullptr` is better.

In C++11 "perfect forwarding" is very important.  It is used everywhere.  Obvious places are `bind` and `function`.  But it is also used in a multitude of other places under the covers.  But "perfect forwarding" isn't perfect.  And one of the places it fails is null pointer constants.

```
template <class T>
void display(T)
{
    std::cout << type_name<T>() << '\n';
}

template <class T>
void
f(T&& t)
{
    display(std::forward<T>(t));  // "perfectly forward" T
}

int main()
{
    f(0);
    f(NULL);
    f(nullptr);
}
```

With an appropriate definition of `type_name<T>()`, on my system this prints out:

```
int
long
std::nullptr_t
```

This can easily make the difference between working code and errors.  With any luck your errors will come at compile time (with horrible error messages).  But you may also get run time errors in some circumstances.

**Aggressively ban use of 0 and NULL in your code.**

Even if you're not perfect forwarding in your code, code you call (such as the std::lib) is very likely using it under the covers.

Comment: Thanks. I used to write 0 always (I was convinced by Stroustop books), and NULL seems to my like red herring, But nowadays still is seen in multiple places. I'll get used now to write nullptr.

Comment: Note that GCC has the option to warn with -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant. "Warn when a literal '0' is used as null pointer constant. This can be useful to facilitate the conversion to nullptr in C++11." http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: But in modern C++ implementations [`NULL` is defined as `nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), isn't it? Then why explicit `nullptr` is better than `NULL`? Or maybe this answer is simply outdated?

Answer (score 30):

Neither, it's `nullptr`.

Though, in your case, I'd just go with

```
if ( !p ){
   //something
}
```

#### 2.14.7 Pointer literals [lex.nullptr]

> 1 The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ Note: `std::nullptr_t`
>   is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is
>   a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.

Comment: You inversed condition. That's why I think it's better to write `p == nullprt` and `p != nullptr`

Comment: +1 after Googling up what `nullptr` actually meant :) This was a new one to me, but a _very_ useful one.

Comment: +1 for `!p`. I find `if(p)` and `if(!p)` much easier to read than the more wordy alternatives.

Comment: if (p) cannot be used to check if a pointer is not null. because it casts to bool, thus potentially loose precious most significant bits. And only would you say otherwise if you have been tainted by Microsoft's compilation behavior, that detects the boolean context and generates != 0 OPCODE.

Comment: @v.oddou: That is not a problem at all, whether or not an actual cast to `bool` occurs (it doesn't). Per [the C++ standard on bool conversions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf#page=101): "A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
prvalue of type bool. _A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true_." (emphasis added) C++ follows C's behavior; most tests care about 0/non-zero, NULL/non-NULL, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Would have upvoted if it weren't for for the `!p`. Using `!` like that obscures the type of `p` and produces more cryptic and less readable code. `x != nullptr` is better for pointers (and reads as 'x is not (equal to) a null pointer'), `x != 0` for integers (and reads as 'x is not (equal to) zero'), and `!x` for booleans (where the boolean ideally has a sensible name like `active`, thus giving `!active` to be read as 'not active').

Answer (score 13):

C++11 has a new literal keyword `nullptr`.  It's better than `0` or `NULL` for things like this because there's no chance it will be used as an `int` in overload resolution.

```
if ( nullptr == p )
```

Or of course you can just use a pointer in a bool context:

```
if ( !p )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same problem in 2019, You are using an older initialization style for unassigned pointers. After 2014 August 14 the C++ 11 released. The compiler you are using is probably following the C++11 standard.

> You can just replace `0/NULL` with `nullptr`

Modern C++ offers `nullptr` as a universal null pointer. You should use that instead of `0 || NULL` because there are some obscure machines that have things like signed pointers where a null pointer is actually something like -1 rather than 0.