# Can '\0' and NULL be used interchangeably?

Tags: c++, null

NULL is often used in the context of pointers, and is defined via macros in multiple standard libraries (such as `<iostream>`) to be the integer `0`. `'\0'` is the null character, and is 8 bits of zeros. Incidentally, 8 bits of zeros is equivalent to the integer `0`.

In some cases, although it is considered to be horrible style, these two can be interchanged:

```
int *p='\0';
if (p==NULL) //evaluates to true
    cout << "equal\n";
```

Or

```
char a=NULL;
char b='\0';
if (a==b) //evaluates to true
    cout << "equal again\n";
```

There are already many similar questions on SO alone; for example, the top answer for this question ([What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)) says "they are not really the same thing."

Could anyone provide an example that `NULL` and `\0` cannot be interchanged (preferably an actual application and not a pathological case)?

Comment: (`-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant`)

Comment: You see this all the time, and it is a terrible anti-pattern

Comment: Biffen, mjs, my question is genuine - I am trying to understand the difference between the two. Are you implying that these two are equivalent and it's just a matter of style (which I presume is the purpose of the gcc flag)?

Comment: You can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091804/whats-better-to-use-in-c11-zero-or-null

Comment: @cwest - no, it is more than style, I have seen real world issues caused by this. I will update my answer with examples later.

Comment: Use C++11 & `nullptr`, not `NULL`

Comment: Some compiler versions allow `virtual void foo () = NULL;`, but no one will allow `'\0'` in the place of `NULL`. Hence, interchanging of `NULL` & `'\0'` is compiler dependent, hence should be avoided.

Comment: See [Bugs found in GCC with the help of PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0425/): the static analyzer found a likely bug because `char*` was compared to `\0`, which made it likely the author had forgotten to dereference the pointer (to get a `char`) before comparing. Proper typing empowers tools.

Comment: `int *p='\0';` this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong.

Comment: @cwest By the way, welcome to StackOverflow, and a good, well written first question

Comment: The following is out of context, but may be worth it.  In SQL databases, such as Oracle, there are two distinct things that need to be expressed.  The first is the variable length character string of length zero.  The second  is the absence of a value, called NULL in SQL.  If you choose the same representation for these two things, you create a mess.  Oracle created just such a mess, more than 25 years ago.  The SQL NULL is not exactly the same thing as the C++ NULL, but they are conceptually close.

Comment: When I first saw the question's title, I thought it was talking about `0` and `NULL`.

Comment: @cwest It was just my way of (lazily) saying that you should always use `nullptr` for null pointers, never `NULL`, `0` or `\0`. It's slightly OT though, since it sort-of invalidates the question.

Answer (score 55):

> Could anyone provide an example that NULL and \0 cannot be interchanged?

The difference between `NULL` and `'\0'` may affect overload resolution.

Example ([check it on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc32a09997ed4946)):

```
#include <iostream>

// The overloaded function under question can be a constructor or 
// an overloaded operator, which would make this example less silly
void foo(char)   { std::cout << "foo(char)"  << std::endl; }
void foo(int)    { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(long)   { std::cout << "foo(long)"  << std::endl; }
void foo(void*)  { std::cout << "foo(void*)" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    foo('\0'); // this will definitely call foo(char)
    foo(NULL); // this, most probably, will not call foo(char)
}
```

Note that the gcc compiler used at Coliru defines `NULL` as `0L`, which for this example means that `foo(NULL)` resolves to `foo(long)` rather than to `foo(void*)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40396865/6394138) discusses that aspect in detail.

Comment: just also call foo(nullptr) for completeness

Comment: This is a bad example, I think, as `foo(NULL)` is more likely to call `foo(int)` than `foo(void*)` on current implementations. Yes, that still isn't `foo(char)`, but `foo(void*)` is more likely to be what the programmer intended.

Comment: On C++, `foo(NULL)` will always call either `foo(int)` or `foo(long)`, because C++ standard disallows defining `NULL` as `(void*)0`. See my answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40396865/5489178

Comment: @hvd This is an excellent example. It clearly shows where `NULL` is not interchangeable with `'\0'`. Not only that but as a cherry on the cake, it reveals an identical problem with `NULL` not being interchangeable with `nullptr`. Sure, the problem isn't described at all, but that's fine in my opinion as long as the answer doesn't suggest using `NULL`. Especially since the problem is a bit off topic to the asked question.

Comment: This is an acceptable example, not an excellent one. After reading this answer, I am left with doubts. Sure, it answers the question, but it could be improved.

Comment: @anatolyg What doubts?

Comment: The real gotcha is when you have `template <typename T> void foo(T)` and then call `foo(NULL)` expecting T to be resolved as some kind of pointer type, but it actually ends up being treated as `foo<int>(NULL)` or `foo<long>(NULL)`

Answer (score 37):

## Definition of macro NULL in C++

[Leon is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395588/5489178) that when there are several overloads for the same function, `\0` would prefer the one that takes parameter of type `char`. However, it is important to notice that on a typical compiler, `NULL` would prefer the overload that takes parameter of type `int`, not of type `void*`!

What probably causes this confusion is that C language allows defining `NULL` as `(void*)0`. C++ standard explicitly states *<sup>(draft N3936, page 444)</sup>*:

> Possible definitions [of macro `NULL`] include `0` and `0L`, but not `(void*)0`.

This restriction is necessary, because e.g. `char *p = (void*)0` is valid C but invalid C++, whereas  `char *p = 0` is valid in both.

In C++11 and later, you should use `nullptr`, if you need a null constant that behaves as pointer.

### How Leon's suggestion works in practice

This code defines several overloads of a single function. Each overload outputs the type of the parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int) {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

void f(long) {
    std::cout << "long" << std::endl;
}

void f(char) {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
}

void f(void*) {
    std::cout << "void*" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(0);
    f(NULL);
    f('\0');
    f(nullptr);
}
```

[On Ideone](http://ideone.com/DVnMAp) this outputs

```
int
int
char
void*
```

Therefore I would claim that the problem with overloads is not an actual application but a pathological case. The `NULL` constant will behave wrong anyway, and should be replaced with `nullptr` in C++11.

## What if NULL is not zero?

Another pathological case [is suggested by Andrew Keeton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296865/5489178) at another question:

> Note that what is a null pointer in the C language. It does not matter on the underlying architecture. If the underlying architecture has a null pointer value defined as address 0xDEADBEEF, then it is up to the compiler to sort this mess out.
>
> As such, even on this funny architecture, the following ways are still valid ways to check for a null pointer:
>
> ```
> if (!pointer)
> if (pointer == NULL)
> if (pointer == 0)
> ```
>
> The following are INVALID ways to check for a null pointer:
>
> ```
> #define MYNULL (void *) 0xDEADBEEF
> if (pointer == MYNULL)
> if (pointer == 0xDEADBEEF)
> ```
>
> as these are seen by a compiler as normal comparisons.

## Summary

All in all, I would say that the differences are mostly stylistic. If you have a function that takes `int` and overload that takes `char`, and they function differently, you will notice difference when you call them with `\0` and `NULL` constants. But as soon as you place those constants in variables, the difference disappears, because the function that is called is deducted from the type of the variable.

Using correct constants makes the code more maintainable, and conveys meaning better. You should use `0` when you mean a number, `\0` when you mean a character, and `nullptr` when you mean a pointer. [Matthieu M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) points out in comments, that [GCC had a bug](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0425/), in which a `char*` was compared to `\0`, whereas the intention was to dereference the pointer and compare a `char` to `\0`. Such errors are easier to detect, if proper style is used thorough the codebase.

To answer your question, there is not really an actual use case that would prevent you from using `\0` and `NULL` interchangeably. Just stylistic reasons and some edge cases.

Comment: My `NULL` (g++ 6.2.0) is `long int`, so the code here doesn't compile unless I add a `long` overload as Leon has (otherwise it's ambiguous between `int` and `char`).

Comment: Why is `NULL` specifically required *not* to be `(void*)`?

Comment: @KyleStrand `char *p = (void *)0;` is valid C but invalid C++. `char *p = 0;` is also valid C++

Answer (score 8):

Please don't do this. It is an anti-pattern, and it is actually wrong. NULL is for NULL pointers, `'\0'` is the null-character. They are logically different things.

I don't think I have ever seen this:

```
int* pVal='\0';
```

But this is fairly common:

```
char a=NULL;
```

But it is not good form. It makes the code less portable, and in my opinion less readable. It is also likely to cause issues in mixed C/C++ environments.

It relies on assumptions regarding how any particular implementation defines NULL. For instance, some implementations use a simple

```
#define NULL 0
```

Others might use:

```
#define NULL ((void*) 0)
```

And I have seen others defining as an integer, and all sorts of odd treatment.

`NULL` should, in my opinion be used solely to indicate an invalid address. If you want a null-character, use `'\0'`. Or define this as `NULLCHR`. But that isn't as clean.

This will make your code more portable- you won't start getting warnings regarding types etc if you change compiler / environment /compiler settings. This might be more important in a C or mixed C/C++ environment.

An example of warnings that might arise: Consider this code:

```
#define NULL 0
char str[8];
str[0]=NULL;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
#define NULL 0
char str[8];
str[0]=0;
```

And we are assigning an integer value to a char. This may cause a compiler warning, and if there are enough occurrences of this, pretty soon you can't see any *important* warnings. And for me, this is the real problem. Having warnings in the code has two side effects:

1. Given enough warnings, you don't spot new ones.
2. It gives the signal that warnings are acceptable.

In both cases, actual bugs can then slip through, that would be caught by the compiler had we bothered to read the warnings (or turn on -Werror )

Comment: `#define NULL (void*) 0` is only valid in C (if parentheses are added), not  in C++. In C++03, `char c = NULL;` is portable but bad style. C++11 allows `#define NULL nullptr`, and `char c = NULL;` is allowed to fail.

Comment: I wasn't aware of C++11 restrictions. This makes the case to not do it even stronger. Will update answer later.

Comment: It's not been a restriction since well before standardisation. It's never(?) been allowed to implicitly convert `void*` to `T*` (for `T != void`) so defining `NULL` to `((void*)0)` would make it pretty useless for most of the contexts it's intended for.

Comment: @CharlesBailey In fairness, both C and C++ have a special conversion from a null pointer constant to any pointer type, even ones that do not allow implicit conversions from other values of the same type. In C, `void (*fp)(void) = (void *) 0;` is valid, even though `void *p = 0; void (*fp)(void) = p;` is invalid. C++ could have had a similar special exception, where `int *ip = (void *) 0;` would be valid, even though `void *p = 0; int *ip = p;` is invalid, just like how `int *ip = 0;` is valid, even though `int i = 0; int *ip = i;` is invalid.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they may exhibit different behaviour while doing resolution of overloaded functions.

`func('\0')` invokes `func(char)`,

while

`func(NULL)` invokes `func(integer_type)`.

---

You can remove the confusion by using [nullptr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant), which is always a pointer type, displays no ambiguity while *assigning/comparing value or function overloading resolution*.

```
char a = nullptr; //error : cannot convert 'std::nullptr_t' to 'char' in initialization
int x = nullptr;  //error : nullptr is a pointer not an integer
```

Note that, it is still compatible with NULL:

```
int *p=nullptr;
if (p==NULL) //evaluates to true
```

Excerpt from C++ Programming Stroustrup 4th Edition book:

> In older code, 0 or NULL is typically used instead of nullptr
>   (§7.2.2). However, using nullptr eliminates potential confusion
>   between integers (such as 0 or NULL) and pointers (such as nullptr).

---

Answer (score 7):

Computer programs have two types of readers.

The first type are computer programs, like the compiler.

The second type are humans, like yourself and your coworkers.

Programs are generally fine with getting one type of zero in place of another.
There are exceptions, as the other answers have pointed out, but that is not really important.

What is important is that you are messing with the *human* readers.

Human readers are *very* context sensitive. By using the wrong zero, you are **lying** to you human readers.  They are going to curse you.

A human that is lied to can overlook bugs more easily.
A human that is lied to can see "bugs" that aren't there. When "fixing" these phanthom bugs, they introduce real bugs.

Don't lie to your humans.  One of the humans you are lying to is your future self.  You are going to curse you too.

Answer (score 4):

Excerpts from C++14 draft N3936:

> #### 18.2 Types [support.types]
>
> 3 The macro `NULL` is an implementation-deﬁned C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10).
>
> #### 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> 1 A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.

Thus, `NULL` can be any integer literal with value zero, or a value of type `std::nullptr_t` like `nullptr`, while `'\0'` is always the zero narrow-character literal.

So, not in general interchangeable, even though in a pointer-context you cannot see any but stylistic difference.

An example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid('\0').name << '\n'
        << typeid(NULL).name << '\n'
        << typeid(nullptr).name << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Let's define what's NULL in C/C++.

According to the C/C++ reference NULL is defined as a macro that expands to a null pointer constant. Next we can read that a null pointer constant can be converted to any pointer type (or pointer-to-member type), which acquires a null pointer value. This is a special value that indicates that the pointer is not pointing to any object.

Definition referring to C:

> A null-pointer constant is an integral constant expression that
>   evaluates to zero (like 0 or 0L), or the cast of such value to type
>   void* (like (void*)0).

Definition referring to C++98:

> A null-pointer constant is an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero (such as 0 or 0L).

Definition referring to C++11:

> A null-pointer constant is either an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero (such as 0 or 0L), or a value of type nullptr_t (such as nullptr).

## Overloading methods example.

Let's assume that we have following methods:

```
class Test {
public:
    method1(char arg0);
    method1(int arg0);
    method1(void* arg0);
    method1(bool arg0);
}
```

Calling method1 with argument `NULL` or `nullptr` should call `method1(void* arg0);`. However if we call method1 with argument `'\0'` or `0` should execute `method1(char arg0);` and `method1(int arg0);`.